# I can't properly pull data from algolia

Tags: php, laravel-8, algolia

I have a Laravel 8.x project. I wanted to pull the `users` table in this project from `Algolia` instead of mysql. The same `users` table is available in `Algolia`. I connected the `users` table with `Algolia` in CreatorController as in the code below.

**CreatorController**

```
public function show($username)
    {
        $client = SearchClient::create(
            env('ALGOLIA_APP_ID'), 
            env('ALGOLIA_SECRET'),
        );
        $index = $client->initIndex("users");

        $creatorData = $index->search($username);
        $creator = $creatorData["hits"][0] ?? null;
        if(count($creatorData["hits"]) == 0 || !isset($creator)){
            abort(404);
        }



        return view('creators.show',[
            'creator' => (object)$creator,
            
        ]);
    }
```

However, when I refresh the page to see the result in localhost, I get the following error.

[image]

I'm putting the part of the code where the error is coming from.

**show.blade.php**

```
                <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
                    @foreach(['linkedin','instagram','twitter','podcast','youtube','website'] as  $value)
                        @if($creator->getCustomField($value)!=null && $creator->getSocialIcons($value)!=null)
                            <a href="{{ $creator->getCustomField($value) }}" target="_blank"><img src="{{ asset($creator->getSocialIcons($value)) }}" alt="{{ ucfirst($value) }}"></a>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </div>
```

**User.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\SearchClient;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, Searchable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function creatorProfile(){
        return $this->hasOne(CreatorProfile::class,'user_id','id');
    }

    public function customFields(){
        return $this->hasMany(UserCustomField::class,'user_id','id');
    }

    public function contents(){
        return $this->hasMany(Course::class,'user_id','id')->where('status_id','=',1);
    }

    public function getCustomField($key){
        $data = collect($this->customFields)->filter(function ($data) use($key){
            return $data->key == $key;
        })->first();

        if($data!=null)
            return $data->value;
    }

    public function getCustomFields($keys){
        return collect($this->customFields)->filter(function ($data) use($keys){
            return collect($keys)->contains($data->key);
        });
    }

    public function getSocialIcons($value){
        //Test Comment
        switch ($value){
            case 'linkedin':
                return 'assets/images/icon-linkedin.svg';
                break;
            case 'instagram':
                return 'assets/images/icon-instagram.svg';
                break;
            case 'twitter':
                return 'assets/images/icon-twitter.svg';
                break;
            case 'podcast':
                return 'assets/images/icon-podcast.svg';
                break;
            case 'youtube':
                return 'assets/images/icon-youtube.svg';
                break;
            case 'website':
                return 'assets/images/icon-website.svg';
                break;

        }
    }

}
```

**The data from Algolia is as follows.**

```
{
  "name": "Adam Shaw",
  "username": "adamshaw",
  "email": "adam@adamshaw.co",
  "avatar": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/creator_thumbnail/741/2022-03-29/thumbnail_400X400_565720_1640103825.jpg",
  "about": "What is important in life?\r\n\r\nI have asked myself this question for as long as I can remember. My path has been varied and fun, which for me is what makes life good.\r\n\r\nMy key expertise is working with energy and mind-body medicine. I also have a more recent background in funding and business consultancy.\r\n\r\nFor 13 years I worked as a nurse, developing key skills and awareness in counselling the dying and their families. Through discussing what was important in life with thousands of people close to death, I noticed certain patterns amongst the regrets and achievements of those close to death. \r\n\r\nIt also led me to discovering energy medicine through Reiki, Vortex Healing and Energetic NLP. This, in turn, led to a path into Mind-Body medicine.\r\n\r\nWhat does all of that mean for you though?\r\n\r\nIf you want to use your mind to improve your wellbeing, I can help. \r\n\r\nIf you are questioning your purpose on the planet, I can facilitate that journey.\r\n\r\nIf you are a company owner looking for help with funding, I can point you in the right direction.",
  "birth_date": "1972-05-02",
  "firebase_user_id": "oa-741",
  "custom_fields": {
    "youtube": "https://www.youtube.com/c/AdamShawTheHeartGuy",
    "linkedin": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/adamshawtheheartguy/",
    "instagram": "https://www.instagram.com/the_heart_guy_/",
    "twitter": "https://twitter.com/adam_shaw",
    "website": "adamshaw.co",
    "email_octopus_id": "ce1b2106-69ec-11ec-96e5-06b4694bee2a",
    "email_octopus_last_update": "2022-03-26 00:46:46",
    "avatar_thumb_400*400": "https://omnicoursewebsites.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/creator_thumbnail/741/2022-03-29/thumbnail_400X400_565720_1640103825.jpg"
  },
  "_tags": [
    "App\\User::741"
  ],
  "objectID": "App\\User::741"
}
```

Comment: You do not have a `User` class instance, you only have a StdClass one - because that is what `(object)$creator` creates, when $creator is an array.

Comment: @CBroe What should I do in this case, I'm really confused by dealing with this algolia.

Comment: Just remove the `(object)` from `'creator' => (object)$creator,` as it should return a `User` object, not a general php object.

Comment: @brance As you said, I removed the (object) part from my code, but this time it started giving another error. `Attempt to read property "name" on array (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs:omnicourse_web_frontend/resources/views/creators/show.blade.php) `

Comment: Can you try using `'creator' => json_decode(json_encode($creator))`?

Comment: @brance Unfortunately it's back to the original error :( `Call to undefined method stdClass::getCustomField() (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs:omnicourse_web_frontend/resources/views/creators/show.blade.php) `

Comment: Do you want to use Algolia for the whole project or just this user search part?

Comment: @brance For now, I want to use Algolia only in this part. Only the creator's page will come from algolia for now.